# WMI Win32_Process WorkingSetSize Vista Issue

Tags: memory, windows-vista, wmi, monitoring

On a system monitoring project, I am retrieving process memory usage through WMI.

I am using Jacob with Java to do the WMI query:

```
SELECT WorkingSetSize FROM Win32_Process
```

This method retrieves the exact memory usage (comparing to task manager) on Windows XP; however on Windows Vista, the memory usage is about 15% higher than the memory displayed in task manager.

The system hardware for each computer is identical. Same memory/processors/etc.

Are there any known issues with retrieving memory usage via Win32_Process.WorkingSetSize on Vista? Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually ended up being an error on my part.

When comparing with the Vista task manager, the memory usage was actually using a different default metric than XP. Vista reports memory usage as Private Working Set, and XP reports memory usage as Working Set. I ended up showing the Working Set column in Vista and everything is exactly correct.